# 2 difrentes logins laravel

Tags: php, laravel, login, laravel-blade

Tengo una aplicación con dos diferentes logins, el registro, la verificación de correo y las vistas apuntan a uno diferente.

**El problema es que si yo hago login en cualquiera de los dos, tengo acceso al otro y eso no debería pasar. alguna idea de como puedo resolver eso?**

no pongo fragmentos de código porque no me parece relevante pero si así lo requieren haganmelo saber.

LOGIN PADRE:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginPadreController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/padre';
    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('tutor');
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('padreguest:tutor')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('loginpadre');
    }
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login-padre');
    }
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        return redirect('/padre');
    }
}
```

LOGIN PROVEEDOR:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/panel';
    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('proveedor');
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:proveedor')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('registro');
    }
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login');
    }
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        return redirect('/panel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás usando el mismo middleware para ambos logins?

Comment: @L.Flor no, son diferentes

Comment: Agrega una variable de sesión para identificar dónde ingresa el usuario, por ejemplo: `$_SESSION['sitio'] = 'sitio1';` y, por supuesto, debes verificarlo en cada lugar donde requieras restringir/otorgar acceso.

Comment: @Triby ya pude lograr mi objetivo usando guards de laravel, pero ahora no me deja iniciar sesión en uno de los paneles

Comment: okey el problema que veo es que el login lo dejas que lo haga automáticamente laravel. En ese caso ocupa el modelo y guard por defecto que esta configurado en el archivo de configuración. Para que funcione deberías de hacer el login manual.

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega pero porque con el de proveedor no tengo ningún problema y con el de tutor si? hay algo malo con el guard? o solo tengo que sobreescribir el método?

Answer (score 0):

para hacer el login con el guard uno:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
class LoginPadreController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/padre';

    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('tutor');
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('padreguest:tutor')->except('logout');
    }

    // hacer que tu ruta de login apunte a este metodo.

   public function login1(Request $request){

      return \Auth::guard('tutor')->attempt($request->all());
   }

    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('loginpadre');
    }
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login-padre');
    }
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        return redirect('/padre');
    }
}
```

Esto iría en tu segundo login.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/panel';
    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('proveedor');
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:proveedor')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('registro');
    }


  // hacer que tu ruta de login apunte a este metodo.

   public function login1(Request $request){
       return \Auth::guard('proveedor')->attepmt($request->all());
   }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login');
    }
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        return redirect('/panel');
    }
}
```

Con esto lograras que no se loguen en el guard web.

Si deseas que al autenticar un usuario se apliquen todos los métodos que utiliza la autentificación  por default puedes establecerlo por medio de los contratos.

Comment: Por qué? en $credentials  debes de pasar los datos del usuario a autenticar. Si es el caso el guard determinara si son correctos. Si no se utiliza el guard el middleware determinara si el usuario tiene acceso a la ruta.

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega ya pude resolver eso, hice diferentes middlewares y guards para cada uno de los dos tipos de usuario que manejo. pero surgió otro problema, cuando utilizo el guard "tutor" no me deja iniciar sesión pero eso no pasa cuando uso el guard "proveedor" en el otro login.

Comment: nos podrias compartir el código de los logins

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega los pongo en la publicación en los comentarios es un poco engorros

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega ya están ambos códigos

Comment: Hay que agregar dos funciones que hagan el attempt para que laravel no utilice el que esta por default. Dame unos minutos y agrego como deberían de quedar tus archivos.

Comment: tristemente esos metodos no me funcionaron me da error 500, y usando el método que esta en la documentación de laravel me sale una pagina totalmente en blanco ni siquiera cambia de url

Comment: en el request hay que pasarle la contraseña y el correo. Puedes poner una captura de pantalla con el error.

Comment: log del error                                                                                                [2020-03-25 15:49:05] production.ERROR: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()

Comment: La app la tengo en un servidor, estuve probando localmente y me arroja un error que no se pudo establecer conexion lo cual esta bien porque mi base tambien esta en un servidor, probe con el guard y si hace referencia a la tabla que tiene que ser, le quite ese guard y hacia referencia a otra tabla, hasta ahí todo bien, por lo que me hace pensar que es el método attemp el que esta fallando

Comment: El error que pasa no es un error del método attempt, Debe de haber algo que este cortando el flujo antes de entrar al método en el controlador. Deberías de probar en el archivo web.php para que no le aplique ningún middleware a los métodos de autentificacion. Es lo que hago cuando no puedo debuguar correctamente.